How to setup and test MTLS in a dummy c# web api
I am trying to fiddle around with certificates and want to implement MTLS, where i can get the caller (request) certificate verify it myself.
No matter what I do, i cant seem to get certificates from request.
app.Use(async (context, next) =>
{
    X509Certificate2 clientCertificate = context.Connection.ClientCertificate;

    if (clientCertificate == null || !clientCertificate.Verify())
    {
        context.Response.StatusCode = 401;
        return;
    }

    // Perform additional validation checks if required

    await next.Invoke();
}

I have added this to my wep api. But no matter what I do, 'clientCertificate' is always null.
I have tried creating a dummy consoleapp also in .net, that makes a simple GET request to my webapi, like this:
// Load the client certificate
X509Certificate2 clientCertificate = new X509Certificate2("C:\\Windows\\System32\\TestCertificate.pfx", "YourPassword");

// Create an HttpClient with MTLS authentication
HttpClient httpClient = new HttpClient(new HttpClientHandler
{
    ClientCertificateOptions = ClientCertificateOption.Manual,
    SslProtocols = SslProtocols.Tls12,
    ServerCertificateCustomValidationCallback = ValidateServerCertificate,
    ClientCertificates = { clientCertificate }
});

// Send the webhook request
HttpResponseMessage response = httpClient.GetAsync("https://localhost:8080/webhook").Result;

Its a self signed certificate as i am doing this locally.
Anyone can help me? I am pretty stuck, and cant understand what I am doing wrong

I suspect you haven't set the server side up to accept a client certificate (by default it says they're not welcome).  Something like https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/security/authentication/certauth?view=aspnetcore-8.0 might be useful (or might be wrong for your usage, hard to say)

Ye have tried that with multiple different settings. Nothing seems to work. I have tried setting ClientCertificateMode.AllowCertificate on the Kestrel webhost. When i open swagger etc it shows me a popup for certificate, but then it gives me error. Not sure if that is due to a autthentication layer before hitting my own code that blocks the certificate?
